# AWS - what's the recommended way to host the client side (HTML, CSS, JS, image files) of a web application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

All tutorials that I've read so far recommend keeping the client code of a web application on S3. However, when making an S3 bucket publicly accessible, I see the following warning:

"You have provided public access to this bucket. We highly recommend that you never grant any kind of public access to your S3 bucket."

What's the recommended way to host the client side of a web application?

[image: AWS public S3 warning]

Comment: It's just a warning. Obviously you would have to make those files public if you want to serve them publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hosting the website public, you can ignore the warning message since it meant to highlight any bucket with open access.

However, this comes with a risk, where if someone continuously accesses the website hosted in S3, it will charge you more and the visibility of access is less.

One option is to whitelist the IP addresses (If you know from where it is being accessed). For more details check the article [How to restrict access to a bucket to specific IP address?](https://wasabi-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000377611-How-to-restrict-access-to-a-bucket-to-specific-IP-address-)

If this is not the case and you are planning to allow access from many different locations, exposing S3 via CloudFront will be useful. This allows, not only to cache the static content in CloudFront, reducing access costs but also speeds up the content delivery through the CDN edge locations. In addition, to that, it will also allow you to directly block any access by region, or add additional security measures such as connecting AWS WAF to block any suspected access.